# HTML5 input autofocus doesn't work

Tags: css, html

I stumble on this case: the autofocus doesn't work while the input field's width is controlled over a button. The focus on click doesn't work either since it triggers the width's animation backward...

I suspect a stupid hierarchy mistake somewhere, so here's a codepen to show you what I did : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPqXdp

Sorry for the basic trouble I'm afraid...

```css
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 700px;
}

.search-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.search-button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.search-form {
  height: 51px;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: width 400ms ease;
  transition: width 400ms ease;
}

.search-form .search-field {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.search-button:focus+.search-form {
  width: 650px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="search-wrap">
    <button class="search-button">?</button>
    <form class="search-form">
      <label>
          <input type="search" class="search-field" autofocus/>
        </label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `autofocus` property works properly in your example. The problem is that when you click the button, the focus changes from your `input` to `button`. **You can only focus on one element at a time**, so it's impossible to do it the way you want it. However you can use `:checked` pseudo class to achieve the same result:

```css
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 700px;
}

.search-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.change-width {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
}

.search-form {
  height: 51px;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: width 400ms ease;
  transition: width 400ms ease;
}

.search-form .search-field {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#change:checked + .search-form {
  width: 650px;
  right: 50px;
}

#change {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="search-wrap">
    <label for="change" class="change-width">?</label>
    <input id="change" type="checkbox">
    <form class="search-form">
       <label>
          <input type="search" class="search-field" id="input">
        </label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can focus onclick. The `autofocus` still won't work since clicking anywhere on the page (on a `label` in this case) will cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to do it with just HTML and CSS.

So the solution i found was to use Javascript to increase the button's width and to focus on the input field at the same time.

```js
const searchWrap = document.querySelector('.search-wrap');
const searchField = document.querySelector('.search-field');
const searchBtn = document.querySelector('.search-button');

searchBtn.addEventListener('focus', function () {
  searchWrap.classList.toggle('active');
  searchField.focus();
});
```

```css
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
}

.search-wrap {
  position: relative;
}

.search-button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.search-form {
  height: 51px;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: width 400ms ease;
  transition: width 400ms ease;
}

.search-form .search-field {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.active .search-form {
  width: 250px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="search-wrap">
    <button class="search-button">?</button>
    <form class="search-form">
      <label>
          <input type="search" class="search-field">
        </label>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


<script>

</script>
```